# Selenium - Checking the first letter of a string in a variable

Tags: selenium

I'd like to know if it's possible, on Selenium IDE, to check the first letter of value inside a variable. For example, I have a variable called cartId, and this variable stores IDs inside it. Sometimes, the ID starts with "A", "E" or "P", examples:

- A324FR
- E289FS
- P23U87

So i'd like to make something like this:

- If starts with A, stores "A" in an auxiliary variable.
- If starts with E, stores "E" in an auxiliary variable.
- If starts with P, stores "P" in an auxiliary variable.

This is needed because depending on the first letter of the value, it will do a different method ... so I can use something like (command, target, value):

- gotoIf | ${auxiliaryVariable} == 'A' | METHOD1
- gotoIf | ${auxiliaryVariable} == 'E' | METHOD2
- gotoIf | ${auxiliaryVariable} == 'P' | METHOD3

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use [`storeEval`](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#storeeval) to evaluate JavaScript to get your auxiliaryVariable

```
storeEval | document.getElementById("cartId").textContent[0] | auxiliaryVariable
```

This will get the element regardless of the text, then store the first letter `A`, `E`, or `P` inside of `auxiliaryVariable` for use later.

Comment: Thanks, but I got this error here: Threw an exception: document.getElementById("cartId") is null ... the variable cartId already has an ID stored in it.

Comment: unfortunately if i don't have any HTML, i can't help further

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help, I could do it using:

- store | javascript{storedVars['cartId'].substring(0,1);} | auxiliary

Comment: I spent time helping you out, and assisting you in thought to how to get to the answer.  Could you please give back by giving me an upvote?  I, like many other people on this site, are professionals just trying to help others out.

Comment: sure, I forgot to press the arrow up button, done ;-)